a problem with getting the Handle for a SUB-process in C#
i have a project that run a multiple windows and i want to to get the handle for one of the sub windows

here i want ot get the handle of it using this code
Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("aaa");
            if (pro.Any())
            {
                IntPtr hwnd = pro[0].MainWindowHandle;
                if (IsIconic(hwnd))
                    ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
                else
                    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
            }

What should be written in GetProcessByName parentheses to get to handle for aaa process

If you really want to capture the main window of separate process with the filename aaa.exe, your attempt should actually work.
But if you want to capture the handle of another window of one process (not the main window) you will have to fetch all the window handles of that specific process.
One way is to use the EnumChildWindows function to enumerate all child windows of a specific parent window. In your case the parent window should be the handle to the main window that you've retrieved using IntPtr hwnd = pro[0].MainWindowHandle.
In order to use the EnumChildWindows function you have to use a DllImport like this one:
[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, Win32Callback callback, IntPtr lParam);

and the Win32Callback should look like this:
public delegate bool Win32Callback(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

So as an example your code would look like this (not tested (!)):
IntPtr parentWindowHandle = pro[0].MainWindowHandle;
EnumChildWindows(parentWindowHandle, Callback, IntPtr.Zero);

...

private static void Callback(IntPtr childWindowHandle, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // Do Something with each handle here...
    // e.g. you could checkt the window title with the GetWindowText function
}


i want the aaa window to show on top of form1 know that "aaa" it's a glut window the code is runnig well for other process and show it's window on top but not for aaa
